# Finding which table a constraint belongs to

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I need to find out which table (name) a particular constraint belongs to.

Does anyone have any TSQL to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many things could be considered to be a constraint:

primary key
foreign key
unique index
check constraint
column default

your question is a little vague.  Do you know the name of the constraint, the type, etc.?

Based on the limited info in your question.  I suggest that you look at the source code to the [master.sys.sp_helpconstraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176038.aspx) stored procedure.

In Sql Server Management Studio, using the Object Explorer, ust navigate to: "Databases" - "System Databases" - "master" - "Programmability" - "Stored Procedures" - "System Stored Procedures" - "sys.sp_helpconstraint".  It contains all the tsql to query all the various kinds of constraints.

Answer (score 44):

This will not find indexes which are in sys.indexes

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id)
FROM
   sys.objects o
WHERE
   o.name = 'MyConstraintName' AND o.parent_object_id <> 0
```

Comment: The query does not produce any results? Pls see post below, as comments do not support formatting.

Comment: And with schema name: `SELECT
   schemas.name, OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id), *
FROM
   sys.objects o 
   left join sys.schemas on o.schema_id=schemas.schema_id
WHERE
   o.name = 'MyConstraintName' AND o.parent_object_id <> 0`

Answer (score 2):

gbn, your solution dosn't seam to work?

```
SELECT
   OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id)
FROM
   sys.objects o
WHERE
   o.name = 'MyConstraintName' AND o.parent_object_id <> 0
```

So if 'MyConstraintName' becomes 'FK_myConstraint'
then the query becomes

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id)
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.name = 'MyConstraintName' 
  AND o.parent_object_id <> 0
```

Which produces no results

```
(No column name)
```

It seams that your 'solution' must be based on a whole lot of unstated assumptions about the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME AS ObjectName
    ,schema_name(o.schema_id) AS SchemaName, OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id) as TableName
    ,type
    ,o.type_desc
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND o.NAME LIKE '%ConstraintUniqueID%'
ORDER BY o.NAME
```